# getting radio button values with different names and same for loop

Tags: php, mysql

How to get the values of these radio button on the same php page or another.

```
 <?php
    $i=1;
    while($i<=5) {
        echo "  
        <input type='radio' name='rating$i' value='1' id='rating_0'>
        <input type='radio' name='rating$i' value='2' id='rating_1'>                                                         
        <input type='radio' name='rating$i' value='3' id='rating_2'>                                                         
        <input type='radio' name='rating$i' value='4' id='rating_3'>                                                      
        <input type='radio' name='rating$i' value='5' id='rating_4'>
    ";
        echo "<br />";
        $i++;
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Maybe with a foreach($_POST){}?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using PHP, I assume you're looking for a server side solution.

In this case, you should surround your inputs with a `form`. E.g.:

```
<form name="myForm" action="myAction.php" method="post">
<?php
    $i=1;
    while($i<=5) {
        echo "  
        <input type='radio' name='rating$i' value='1' id='rating_0'>
        <input type='radio' name='rating$i' value='2' id='rating_1'>                                                         
        <input type='radio' name='rating$i' value='3' id='rating_2'>                                                         
        <input type='radio' name='rating$i' value='4' id='rating_3'>                                                      
        <input type='radio' name='rating$i' value='5' id='rating_4'>
    ";
        echo "<br />";
        $i++;
    }
    ?>
</form>
```

`myAction.php` is the page where you process the form data; you can choose between `post` and `get` methods, depending on your needs. If you choose `post`, as I wrote in the example, inside `myAction.php` you'll find your input values inside `$_POST` array.

For this simple example you'll have:

`$_POST['rating1']`, `$_POST['rating2']`, ..

If you already know that there will be 5 inputs, you can use a cycle inside `myAction.php` as well:

```
while($i<=5) {
    // do something with $_POST["rating$i"]
}
```

**Update:**
If you know that you only have these inputs, you could loop through all the `$_POST` values as such:

```
foreach($_POST as $val){
    // do something with $val
}
```

If you don't know the number of inputs, but you know that they'll be all called "ratingX", you could loop through all `$_POST` values and look for those starting with "rating" (not the best optimized solution):

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $val){
    if(substr($key, 0, 6) == 'rating'){
        // do something with $val
    }
}
```

Comment: hi Lorenzo! thanks for the answer, but i am not sure about the number of inputs, there can by any number of questions, can you suggest what should i do in that case?

Comment: i have a question here, the variable $val treats as a value of the radio button, and i am getting the right value in the code you suggested and i wrote, but now the question is, what if i want to have more than one values in the loop, this was for just the radio button, lets say i have 3 text fields and one radio button. can you tell me how to get the values of all form inputs?

Comment: the `foreach($_POST as $val)` code snippet would work for every input in the form, so you can start from there

Comment: how would it differentiate weather it is rating, question id, question or answer?

Comment: well we're moving a little bit off the original question, and SO is not exactly an helpdesk :) we're not in the code 'design' field now. A trivial solution would be giving different names/prefixes to different inputs (eg. radio1, radio2.., questionid, question1, question2.., answer1, answer2.. and so on)

Comment: :) i know but i am stuck at this, thanks for helping, but let me tell you what exactly i am doing, i am designing a survey system and there would be number of questions and answers coming in a while loop and i am storing the survey filled by the customers, for the same i need the different form values. i am very much thankful to you for helping on this

Answer (score 0):

Try to include one form and add this.

```
<form action="page.php" action="post">
<?php
    while($i<=5) {
            echo "  
            <input type='radio' name='rating$i' value='1' id='rating_0'>
            <input type='radio' name='rating$i' value='2' id='rating_1'>                                                         
            <input type='radio' name='rating$i' value='3' id='rating_2'>                                                         
            <input type='radio' name='rating$i' value='4' id='rating_3'>                                                      
            <input type='radio' name='rating$i' value='5' id='rating_4'>
        ";
            echo "<br />";
            $i++;
        }
?>
</form>
```

You can access the values from `$_POST` array in action page of form like

```
foreach($_POST() as $radioval)
{
echo $radioval;
}
```

Comment: actually the OP's code would work because `$i` would be expanded because it is inside a double quotes string

Answer (score 0):

you could do to get the values (not selected values)

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="rating$i"]'); //where rating$i is rating1 rating 2 and so on
for (var element in elements)
{
    var value=element.value;
}
```

to get the selected values you must simply check

```
var value = rating$i.value;   //rating1 rating2 and so on
```